# SQL Server 2008 login error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to login to SQL SERVER 2008 from another computer (IP is 10.225.3.137).
The database name is MSSQLSERVER2008, TCP protocol is port 49172.
The account is SQL Server Authentication.

1. I read from an article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017#port) to login to the database engine from another computer. Server name is "tcp:10.225.3.137,49172" and it works.
   Here is the sceenshot:

[image]

2. I try to login from another computer to this database with server name is "10.225.3.137\MSSQLSERVER2008" but it doesn't work. Here is the screenshot. However, with the same server name on computer that installed SQL SERVER 2008, it works.

[image]

Anyone here can explain for me please? And how to login to that database from another computer with server name is "10.225.3.137\MSSQLSERVER2008"?

Comment: What is "MSSQLSERVER2008" ? Instance name? Machine name? Or database name? You would only use it like that if it is an instance name. And you would still add the portif it is not on default 1433.

Comment: The "database name" is MSSQLSERVER2008? I *assume* you actually mean the instance name. Is your target instance also really running on port 49172? By default, it is runs on 1433. Do you have named piped enabled on the destination server? Is the firewall enabled on the server, and if so is port 49172 open 9if that really is the port it's on)?

Comment: @Larnu yes, I set the port to 49172 and open port on Firewall. I login succesfully both computers in the first image. The 2nd image, it works only on computer that installed SQL SERVER 2008, another computer doesnt work.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I login succesfully both computers in the first image. The 2nd image, it works only on computer that installed SQL SERVER 2008, another computer doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that SQL server is listening on default port and is set up for remote access and firewall is set up for default port 1433 and TCP/IP connections are enabled.

Looking at both images, it looks like it is not listening on port 1433 but 49172. Then change your connection to read:

```
10.225.3.137,49172\MSSQLSERVER2008
```

(you might prefix with tcp:)

Note: I have an old series of videos on youtube if you kike to watch, that shows setting up SQL server express locally and then connecting from remote using a custom port (search for "AccuSQL installation" on youtube and you would see 4 parts of videos - part 3 or 4 was about remote connection).

And BTW that is called an "INSTANCE" not database.